# Shuffling NSArray and using the shuffled array to change switch cases. Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I’m beginner in Objective C programming and I’ve been struggling with this for the past few days. 
I have a NSMutableArray called tasks, that I’m accessing in switch statement to change switch cases like this

`- (IBAction)random:(id)sender {
    int text = [[self.tasks objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
    x++;`

which works flawlessly. But when I try to randomize/shuffle the tasks array by one of the methods showed bellow it just shows `case 0` of the `switch`. I want to be able to use the newly shuffled array to change the switch cases. Am I on the right track or is something like this even possible?

ViewController.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m


#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import "NSMutableArray_Shuffling.h"

@import GameKit;

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navback.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}






-(NSMutableArray*) tasks {
    tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:4] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:6] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:7] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:8] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:9] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:11] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:12] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:13] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:14] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:15] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:16] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:17] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:18] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:19] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:20] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:21] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:22], nil];

    return tasks;
}

int x=0;
int z=9999;
int k=0;

//Neither of these shuffle methods work.

/*
 - (void)shuffle
 {
 NSUInteger count = [tasks count];
 if (count < 1) return;
 for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i) {
 NSInteger remainingCount = count - i;
 NSInteger exchangeIndex = i + arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t )remainingCount);
 [tasks exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:exchangeIndex];
 }
 }

 -(void)shuffle
 {
 shuffledTasks = [[GKRandomSource sharedRandom] arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray:tasks];

 }

 */


// This is for checking if x is > than the number of elements in my tasks array, then reseting it and shuffling the array so a new order of elements is presented for the switch. But it works only for reseting the x.
-(void)reset{
    if (x>22) {
        x=0;
        [self shuffle];



    }
}

//The switch, which currently only pulls objectAtIndex:x from the original tasks array. No matter how I try to shuffle it.

- (IBAction)random:(id)sender {
    int text = [[self.tasks objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
    x++;


    switch (text) {

        case 0:
            z=0;
            //something magical will happen
            [self reset];
            break;

        case 1:
            z=1;
            //something magical will happen
            [self reset];
            break;

        case 2:
            z=2;
            //something magical will happen
            [self reset];
            break;

        case 3:
            z=3;
            //something magical will happen
            [self reset];
            break;

        case 4:
            z=4;
            //something magical will happen
            [self reset];
            break;

//cases 5-21…

        case 22:
            z=22;
            //something magical will happen
            [self reset];
            break;


        default:
            z=9999;


    }
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Accounts/Accounts.h"
@import GameKit;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    //Here should be declared everything for the Main.storyboard but it's unnecessarily long and it works, so no need to post it here.

    NSMutableArray *tasks;
    NSArray *shuffledTasks;
    NSMutableArray *zamichano;

}




- (void)TimerCount;
- (void)shuffle;

- (IBAction)random:(id)sender;
//Again, here would be things for the storyboard.



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

where do you set the value for x ?
either way add this line

```
int x = arc4random_uniform(self.tasks - 1);
```

above this one

```
int text = [[self.tasks objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
```

and it should work perfectly (assuming that the elements in self.tasks are of the "value type" otherwise you ll get zero in here :

```
int text = [[self.tasks objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
```